# How to start parallel human tasks

Tags: jbpm

I want to asynchronously start multiple number of human tasks, then wait till they all end, and after - continue proccess.Is it even possible to do?

Comment: It does sound funny to suggest a program to start human tasks. But I understand it to mean some outside stimulus indicates the human task is accepted by a human who says they are starting it and then another outside stimulus indicates that it is complete.

Comment: and thus skynet was born ;)

Comment: Sorry for poor english. I want to start parallel human tasks (user tasks) from jbpm process

Comment: This question is a bit too vague to be easily answerable: can you add any more details here?

Answer (score 0):

yes.. you can define a parallel gateway in your process and start as many tasks as you want. 
How does your business process looks like?

Comment: During process I'm sending some kind of document to number of users. They have to approve it. So, I couldn't implement parallel gateway, because I don't know how many parallel branches i have to create.

Comment: Well but you can use a Multi Instance node with a User Task inside..Then using a variable you will define the number of instances that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-instance subprocess, Human Task can be build-in it.